# Use a linq query as microsoft local report Data Source (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, report

How can I use a linq query as local report(Microsoft Report) data source (WinForms)?
I have a Microsoft Report Viewer Control in MyForm,And I have a linq query as this :

```
var query = from colV in dal.v_TarafeGharardad join colT in dal.TBL_TarafeGharardad on colV.Id equals colT.PK_Id  select colV;
```

I want to use the linq query as Microsoft Report Data Source.
I have try this,but I really know it is wrong.

```
frmReportViewer ReportViewerForm = new frmReportViewer();
            ReportViewerForm.rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("v_TarafeGharardad",query));
            ReportViewerForm.rptViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Application.StartupPath + "rptTarafeGharardad.rdlc";
            ReportViewerForm.Show();
```

What is the solution?(Thanks :-*)

**Update**: If I can convert the linq query to DataTable,the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing looks pretty much correct. I do exactly that (this is VB):

```
rptViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = <filepath>
rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("<data_source_name_in_report>", <linq_query_result>))
rptViewer.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout)
```

The one bit you need to check is that you are matching the datasource name that is in the report correctly. You can check this by opening the report in a text editor and looking in the datasources element.

The other thing from memory, and I've not used this in about a year so I might be wrong, I've got a niggling feeling you have to call either `rptViewer.Refresh()` or `rptViewer.SetDisplayMode()` to force it to render.

Take a look at this website for plenty of info on the ReportViewer control:

http://www.gotreportviewer.com/